# How do I link a npm package into my html? (e.g. aos)

Tags: html, node.js, npm

I'm just learning the basics of node.js and npm at the moment and please forgive me if this is a very noob-question.

I just learned how to load a npm package (npm install modulename). It's now located in the folder »node_modules« and in my »package.json« - but how do I connect this with my html page now?

For example:
`npm install aos`

I want to use it in my html. I have the index.html and the index.js in my root-folder. In this folder is also the /node_modules:

```
root

-- node_modules

------ aos

------ …

-- index.html

-- index.js
```

In my index.html I put this:
`<script src="index.js"></script>`

In my index.js I thought I just need to put this:

```
var AOS = require('aos');
AOS.init();
```

But this doesn't work.

What do I need to do to tell my index.js to import my node_module? :/

Thank you!

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: = I can't use aos (or any other package) in my html. As if the link was wrong.

Comment: What is the error message you get? Have you read the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/aos?

Comment: there is no error message. and yes i read it. but would you say that this is the correct way to import a package, like i did?

Comment: Did you end up getting it to work? @d24